# Django admin custom CSS files insertion order

Tags: css, django, django-templates

When adding some custom CSS to your ModelAdmins, you usually do something like this:

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": ("my_custom_styles.css", )
        }
```

My problem is that such style sheets are added BEFORE third-party apps style sheets, making it impossibile to override them easily (in fact, they override the custom styles):

```
<link href="my_custom_styles.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="base_styles.css"      type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I'd like to swap such order. Is there any easy way to accomplish that?

Comment: You should have a look at django.contrib.admin templates and maybe override one of them

Comment: Off-topic but sorry, I couldn't help it: http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/02/26/nothing-is-more-important-than-the-cascade/